# Placing one HTML element(div) over another(li)

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster, interact.js

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) along with [Interact](https://github.com/taye/interact.js).I basically want to add images on the widgets with the help of [Interact](https://github.com/taye/interact.js).For now I am just trying to place the *interact* widget on the *gridster* widget.But when I try to place the *interact* widget over *gridster* widget it goes below *gridster* widget.I want *interact* widget to be over *gridster* widget.How can I do that

I have tried with `z-index` but its still not working the way I want

My JS:

```
 // target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },
    // enable autoScroll
    autoScroll: true,

    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    // call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.pageX - event.x0, 2) +
                     Math.pow(event.pageY - event.y0, 2) | 0))
            .toFixed(2) + 'px');
    }
  });

  function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  // this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
  window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;

  /* The dragging code for '.draggable' from the demo above
 * applies to this demo as well so it doesn't have to be repeated. */

// enable draggables to be dropped into this
interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
  // only accept elements matching this CSS selector
  accept: '#yes-drop',
  // Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
  overlap: 0.75,

  // listen for drop related events:

  ondropactivate: function (event) {
    // add active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.add('drop-active');
  },
  ondragenter: function (event) {
    var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget,
        dropzoneElement = event.target;

    // feedback the possibility of a drop
    dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target');
    draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop');
    draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in';
  },
  ondragleave: function (event) {
    // remove the drop feedback style
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
    event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop');
    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out';
  },
  ondrop: function (event) {
    event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
  },
  ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
    // remove active dropzone feedback
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-active');
    event.target.classList.remove('drop-target');
  }
});
```

**Update**

The Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jry7z2e8/12/) according to answer given by [myfunkyside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3407923/myfunkyside)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jry7z2e8/7/)

Comment: If the question needs more clarification please ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add these two rules for `.drag-drop.can-drop`:

- `position:absolute;`
- `z-index:n;` (with `n` being a higher number than all the Gridster-widgets, say `9999`)

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks So much :)

Comment: Is it possible that once placed in gridster widget it should remain within the boundaries of gridster widget when the gridster widget is moved.But if I move the interact widget out of the gridster widget it will come out

Comment: @NewBie sorry for the long silence, I've been trying to get this to work for quite some time, but all my efforts seem to get stuck by the two libraries working against each other. **This is one of my last efforts: [https://jsfiddle.net/jry7z2e8/18/](https://jsfiddle.net/jry7z2e8/18/)**, you can change the "18" in the URL to "19" up to "21" (or lower obviously) to check out some other versions. Maybe you can get it working, I don't think I'm able to.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort that you have put into.And no worries over the delay.Atleast you have dedicated your efforts which will guide me in right direction atleast if not give me the entire solution

Comment: Thank you so much for it :)